# Is there any possibility to search an asset with partial id

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

In hyperledger-fabric node js sdk.
Is there any possibility to search an asset with partial id?
for example my id is 'abc123'.
I can search with bc12 or abc or 123..and get the matching results.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stub.GetStateByRange(startKey, endKey)` it is possible to retrieve results on a partial key, if they key has a specific form.

For eg.
the following keys could be used to successfully with a range query in the chaincode to retrieve a list of results, to match key **abc123**

```
a  
ab  
abc  
abc1  
abc12  
abc123
```

However, a key without the same initial characters will not work. Eg. bc12 or 123.

The below function [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim#ChaincodeStubInterface) gives a good idea of how the `GetStateByRange` function can be used.

```
    // GetStateByRange returns a range iterator over a set of keys in the
    // ledger. The iterator can be used to iterate over all keys
    // between the startKey (inclusive) and endKey (exclusive).
    // However, if the number of keys between startKey and endKey is greater than the
    // totalQueryLimit (defined in core.yaml), this iterator cannot be used
    // to fetch all keys (results will be capped by the totalQueryLimit).
    // The keys are returned by the iterator in lexical order. Note
    // that startKey and endKey can be empty string, which implies unbounded range
    // query on start or end.
    // Call Close() on the returned StateQueryIteratorInterface object when done.
    // The query is re-executed during validation phase to ensure result set
    // has not changed since transaction endorsement (phantom reads detected).
    GetStateByRange(startKey, endKey string) (StateQueryIteratorInterface, error)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Clyde is the correct one to your question.

But, if you intend to perform complex queries in your code and you are in a position to refactor your data modelling, maybe you can set the information you must filter in some field inside your model (instead of or in addition to the ID itself) and perform rich queries against that field.

To do this, you must enable [CouchDB as the state DB](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html) in your peers if haven't done it yet. Then you can [query the DB](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.2/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getQueryResultWithPagination__anchor) and [perform rich queries against your model fields](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.1/api/database/find.html#selector-basics).

Of course, this is not the answer to your question, but it may fit better to your use case if you are in a position to perform this kind of changes.